# Retrieve position from HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary

I research a position of my key in hashMap.
Example :

> ```
>     HashMap<Integer, String> ht = new HashMap();
>     ht.put(1, "c");
>     ht.put(10, "b");
>     ht.put(8, "r");
>
>     System.out.println(ht);
> ```

10 has position 3 in `HashMap`, 8 has position 2 ...

So I have two questions :

1. how to retreive these positions from HashMap?
2. When i have a much element, i use hashMap to retreive a positions or Binary Search ?

Comment: There's no such thing as position in a HashMap

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is not a sorted or ordered [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementation, so there isn't a "position" here.

[`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is an ordered one, [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a sorted one.

Comment: OK Thanks ! and How about binary search or find a position from LinkedHashMap/TreeMap ?

Comment: Ok ! but how is the best on complexity ? using Binary seach on simple table or using LinkedHashMap/TreeMap ? to found a position

Comment: First, if you want to play with binary search, I suggest you use a List and use Collections.sort and Collections.binarySearch

Comment: The above methods have an O(n*logn) for sort and O(logn) for binary search complexities in worst cases.

Answer (score 2):

A hash map is not ordered, so there are no real concepts of positions in a hashmap. If you need an ordered/sorted map, have a look at TreeMap or LinkedHashMap.